# RealTime QImage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

I'm generating regularly cv::Mat that I'm displaying as soon as it's ready to be displayed, in a separate window. It's kind of a RealTime cv::Mat.

I didn't find a way to display the Mat in my GUI so that it would be updated everytime (with the RealTime cv::Mat

Is there a way to update everytime my QImage without establishing any pushButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add any buttons for this. Use [signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

So when your image is regenerated on a different thread, you emit a signal. And when this signal comes, you update your QImage and display it.